# How to optimize vCSA Tiny peformance housed over 100 VMS?

Tags: vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

vSphere Cluster is 3x HPE DL380 G8 with 128GB RAM on board connected to 3PAR. The total number of running VMs is over 60. Although the vCSA deployment size is Tiny meaning there should be the enough resources to maintain the production, the project I currently work on requires the installation of over than 50 VMs more. Therefore, I need to ensure the vCSA configuration could handle the desired workload until we are ready to update the vCSA configuration.

By following the recommendations https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/vmware-vcenter-server-appliance-homelab-tips I have already lowered from 8 to about 7Gb RAM by disabling updates, vsan health service, dump collector and HTML5 UI. Is there anything else can be tweaked?

Comment: I'm sorry. What is the specific question? Is there a problem right now?

Comment: @ewwhite there is no problem with the performance at the moment. Due to vCSA Tiny deployment, I need to ensure somehow that vCenter can house more than 100 VMs, since we are not ready to update it in the nearest future.

Comment: vCSA recommended sizing isn't as specific as something like a NGFW where you have bandwidth limits per features etc etc, Tiny is fine for 100 and likely even 250 VMs if you aren't doing every possible feature available on the vCSA

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend to disable also VMware Performance Charts and VMware Content Library Service. Check the list in the source to disable more unused service in your configuration.
Source: http://www.virten.net/2017/02/homelab-downsizing-vcenter-server-appliance-6-5/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it will work.

https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2106572

```
Notes:
Tiny Environment (up to 10 Hosts, 100 Virtual Machines)
Small Environment (up to 100 Hosts, 1,000 Virtual Machines)
Medium Environment (up to 400 Hosts, 4,000 Virtual Machines)
Large Environment (up to 1,000 Hosts, 10,000 Virtual Machines)
```

If you find that you need more resources for your vCSA, add RAM or CPU to it.
I don't think your environment will simply fall over if you cross the 100 VM threshold.

Am I missing something?

Comment: at 101 VM's it's not going to just shut down either. lol

Answer (score 1):

One other option might be to backup your tiny VCSA and restore it to a newly-deployed small VCSA.